# Call Javascript from a PHP variable

Tags: php, javascript

I have a form that calls a success message with this code:

```
// Form processed successfully, return the success message
$result = array(
    'type' => 'success',
    'data' =>      
    $form->replacePlaceholderValues($successMessage)
);
```

the variable `$successMessage` is called if the form is successfully sent.

```
$successMessage = '<div class="success-message">Your message has been sent, thank you.</div>';
```

I want to process this Javascript popup rather than the success message using this code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $().socialTrafficPop({
        timeout: 999,
        title: "One Great Site!",
        message: '<div class="success-message">Your message has been sent, thank you.</div><em>Share Send Email Free</em>!',
        google_url: "http://tyler.tc/",
        fb_url: "somesite.com",
        closeable: true,
        advancedClose: false,
        opacity: '0.45',
        twitter_method: "tweet",
        tweet_url: 'somesite.com',
        tweet_text: 'Just tried out this awesome plugin Social Traffic Pop - Its Amazing!'
    });
});
</script>
```

Can I call it from the variable `$successMessage`?  Or is there a better and more appropriate way to call this script?  How would I do either?

Also, I put the necessary scripts inside of the `header.php` file which gets called by the `index.php` file which projects the homepage. Is there somewhere else I should be putting the necessary scripts that the popup code needs to function rather than `header.php`?

I have tried endlessly around the code below and it doesn't seem to work.  The `$successMessage` works without the JavaScript fine, but when I try to add the JavaScript the form will not process anymore. Here is one of the many things I have tried. Thank you for any help.

```
<?php
$successMessage = echo "
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){          
        $().socialTrafficPop({
            timeout: 999,
            title: "One Great Site",
            message: '<div class="success-message">Your message has been sent, thank you.</div><em>Share Send Email Free</em>!',
            google_url: "http://tyler.tc/",
            fb_url: "someurl.com",
            closeable: true,
            advancedClose: false,
            opacity: '0.45',
            twitter_method: "tweet",
            tweet_url: 'someurl.com',
            tweet_text: 'Just tried out this awesome!'
        });
    });
    </script>";
```

Comment: You're mixing `"` in PHP and Javascript in the `script` block you're trying to `echo` (and I doubt you need the `$successMessage` variable). You need to either escape the `"` (like so: `\"`) within the Javascript, or use `'` instead. Note, if you look at the code highlighting above, you'll notice that the `script` tag text is alternately red and highlighted in different colors. This is an indicator of a problem.

Comment: Have a look at [`heredoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Comment: output buffering via [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) may also be a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quote escaping is not right; you either need to replace the `"` within the Javascript with `'`, escape the `\"` if you have to, or as Felix Kling notes, use a `heredoc`.

```
<?php

echo "
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){          
        $().socialTrafficPop({
            timeout: 999,
            title: 'One Great Site',
            message: '<div class=\"success-message\">Your message has been sent, thank you.</div><em>Share Send Email Free</em>!',
            google_url: 'http://tyler.tc/',
            fb_url: 'someurl.com',
            closeable: true,
            advancedClose: false,
            opacity: '0.45',
            twitter_method: 'tweet',
            tweet_url: 'someurl.com',
            tweet_text: 'Just tried out this awesome!'
        });
    });
    </script>
";

?>
```

http://codepad.org/lsqLVXs4

Comment: Your answers led me to use a new function which processed the code after the success message.
    successEnd: function () {
since I couldn't figure out how to move forward inside of the PHP code.  Rather than replace the success message with new code I enabled the code to process after the success message.  The $successMessage variable was locked in a php file however, the actual message was initiated by .js file which made it much easier to integrate the code.